# Find $h(x,y) = g(f(x,y))$ and the set in which $h$ is continuous.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find $h(x,y) = g(f(x,y))$.

I'm given:
$$g(t)=t^2+\sqrt{t}$$ and $$f(x,y) = 2x+3y - 6$$

I looked at the solution and I can see that I'm supposed to set $f(x,y)=0$ by making $2x+3y-6=0$. I understand how to plug that into $g(t)$ and find the proper domain values, my question is why do I have to make $f(x,y)=0$? Why couldn't I plug $2x+3y$ into $g(t)$? or even plug $6$ into $g(t)$?

Comment: Perhaps $f(x,y)$ should be $2x+3y-6$, rather than $2x+3y=6$?

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ hint:  put a backslash before sqrt and you get the sqrt sign:  \sqrt t gives $\sqrt t$  If the argument is more than one character, put it in braces, so \sqrt {x+y} gives $\sqrt {x+y}$

Answer (score 0):

Given that $f(x,y)=2x+3y-6$  you can plug that into $g(t)$.  The reason you plug that instead of $2x+3y$ or $6$ into $g$ is that you were asked for $g(f(x,y))$

Comment: Ah, I looked at my picture of the book and the minus sign looks like an equal sign.